# DJANGO: Set site_id to sites pk

Tags: python, django

I am following [this tutorial](https://medium.com/@frfahim/django-registration-with-confirmation-email-bb5da011e4ef) for email verification.The version the author is working with is old.I got an error that said
`Reverse for ‘activate’ with keyword arguments ‘{‘uidb64’: b’OA’, ‘token’: ‘4tm-3fcfb375c8ba14f9a95b’}` . I got that fixed through the first comment . The email got sent .But the link led to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) . The second comment tells how to fix that . The comment was :
For those are using Django 3, You should change some code

1. Six is deprecated in Django 3, you can use ‘import six’ instead of ‘from django.utils import six’
2. To send html email, add
   email.content_subtype = “html”
   after EmailMessage Object.
3. activate url should be
   path(‘activate//’, views.activate, name=’activate’),
4. get_current_site(request) will return example.com as default when SITE_ID=1 in your settings.py. Add your site name and domail in admin site (/admin/sites/site/) and replace SITE_ID with your sites pk.

But I did not understand how to set SITE_ID to my sites pk.

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py` set

```
BASE_URL = 'https://www.yourdomainname.com'
```

Don't include trailing `/`
Also, you have to mention this line in the same file

```
SITE_ID = 1
```

Moreover, go to your `django admin` pannel , default is `/admin`, and go to the `sites` tab/model and add/edit your `site` according to your `ip/domainName` and `display name` . This is the `important part` to do.

If you are testing locally for now then you can use `127.0.0.1:8000` in your `ip/domainName` and `yourdomainNAme.com` in `display name`

If you are deploying or using live then you can use actual ip of your server into `ip/domainname` or also you can use your domain name (as it's mapped to your ip via DNS system) and display name will be the same.

Hope, it will resolve your problem or issue.

Comment: Thanks , just a question , in the admin panel , should there be a trailing / ? And how according to ip ? And should I delete www.example.com?

Comment: I have edited the answer , how to use ip for locally. you can check your `urls.py` to know whether it's  `/admin` or `/admin/` , so use it accordingly. most probably it will be `/admin`

Comment: Should I delete www.example.com in /admin? Activate linke still leads to example.com .

Comment: yeah delete it from the admin panel and create a new one according to your requirement.

Comment: Hmm ..... I had to create a new project as after deleting example.com , the project would not run .

Comment: It's not working...

Comment: dude you can edit it if you don't want to delete. just click on the `ip/domainname` and then you can edit and save

Comment: and if you are creating a new one then you can use its id. like `SITE_ID=2` in your `settings.py`

Comment: SITE_ID = 2 , sites : 
1) Domain name : www.example.com
    Display name:example.com

2)Domain name : http://127.0.0.1:8000/
    Display name:  http://127.0.0.1:8000/                                                                       it still does not work .

Comment: 1st thing. Display name should be domain name not ip. in domain name you can use ip. 2nd thing I'll suggest delete the 2nd one and edit the first one itself. domain name: 127.0.0.1:8000 , display name: yourdomainname.com , SITE_ID=1 and BASE_URL="http://www.yourdomainname.com"